# Vim: can indentation use spaces after non-whitespace?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to make VIM use spaces for tabs, when the cursor has non-whitespace characters before it?

eg:

(Assuming TAB is `--->`, `•` is a space.)

```
--->function(arg);••••••/* comment */
    //            ^ use spaces when pressing TAB after non-whitespace chars.
```

Otherwise I want real tabs when pressing tab.

*This is useful when tabs are used for initial indentation, but the alignment for all text after uses spaces.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to do automatically without scripting or a plugin.

The "Smart Tabs" plugin was designed for this task. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=231

To make the problem happen a little less frequently there are the built-in `preserveindent` and `copyindent` options to prevent losing your existing tab indent when `expandtab` is set.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:set expandtab`.
This will expand all tabs to spaces, during insert, even the ones at the beginning of the line (which probably is the best).
Use `CTRL-V<Tab>` to insert a tab.

From `vim` help (`:help expandtab`)

```
'expandtab' 'et'        boolean (default off)
                        local to buffer
                        {not in Vi}
        In Insert mode: Use the appropriate number of spaces to insert a
        <Tab>.  Spaces are used in indents with the '>' and '<' commands and
        when 'autoindent' is on.  To insert a real tab when 'expandtab' is
        on, use CTRL-V<Tab>.  See also :retab and ins-expandtab.
        NOTE: This option is reset when 'compatible' is set.
```

Use `:set shiftwidth=4` (or `:set shiftwidth=8`) to control how many spaces are added per indent.

```
'shiftwidth' 'sw'       number  (default 8)
                        local to buffer
        Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent.  Used for
        'cindent', >>, <<, etc.
```

Other settings of interest are `softtabstop`, `tabstop` and `autoindent`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, re: `even the ones at the beginning of the line (which probably is the best).` - is exactly what I don't want. I realize the answer to my question may well be _"VIM cant do this"_.

Comment: @ideasman42 Would a key map (`noremap <F8> :set invexpandtab expandtab?<CR>`) help? That would allow you to switch `expandtab` on and off when you need. However, there could be a better solution.